# Want to get selected value

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
declare @qry as varchar(max)
declare @db as varchar(25)
declare @item as varchar(25)
declare @U_Parentcode as varchar(25)


set @U_Parentcode ='CDM51306520'
set @db ='Marda_Test'
set @qry ='select @item =itemcode from ' + @db + '.[dbo].[OITM]  where ItemCode=''' + @U_Parentcode +''''
execute (@qry)
print @item
```

am getting error like 'Must declare the scalar variable "@item".'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic sql executes in a different context from the context of your code, so basically there isn't an `@item` variable declared over there.

You need to use [`sp_executeSql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which contains a mechanism to map your variables to variables within the block. The syntax is a but obtuse, but it's obvious when you get used to it.

```
declare @qry as nvarchar(max)
declare @db as varchar(25)
declare @outsideItem as varchar(25)
declare @U_Parentcode as varchar(25)

set @U_Parentcode ='CDM51306520'
set @db ='Marda_Test'
set @qry ='select @insideItem =itemcode from ' + @db + '.[dbo].[OITM]  where ItemCode=''' + @U_Parentcode +''''

execute sp_executesql @qry, N'@insideItem varchar(25) output', @insideItem = @outsideItem output
print @item
```

The first parameter is the query, same as with `exec()`.
The second parameter is a declaration of all parameters used in the query, in your case `@insideItem`.
The third (and any subsequent) parameter is a mapping that says which inside parameter should be mapped to which outside parameter.
The output clause (used both on the variable declaration and on the mapping) is a designator that that parameter is used as an output value of the query.

Comment: it show errorIncorrect syntax near '@insideItem varchar(25) output'.

Comment: Sorry, the `N` for nvarchar needs to be uppercase :)

Comment: Here's and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bb7b/8) with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `declare` statements are not included in `@qry` content.

In addition, why are you even bothering with `execute` ?
Why not just use a normal query.  Parameterize your connection string so that you connect to the correct database and just run a normal query.